# Create json object in php foreach loop

Tags: parsing, foreach, json

I have the following in php:

```
$follow=explode(" ",$_SESSION['Following']); //create array from the string stored in     session variable

foreach($follow as $val) {
  $show = $val;

    //my query

$result=mysqli_query($dbc,$query);

WHILE ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

  //$array[]= $rows; // tried this
  //$array=json_encode($rows); //tried this
  //array_push($array,$rows); // tried this
        }
$json_array=json_encode($array);

    echo $json_array;
```

If I take a single pass through the foreach loop the json object looks like this: 
[{key:value}....], which can be parsed in my javascript.
However, with multiple passes in the foreach I am getting multiple arrays
within the object ,like this: [{key:value}][{key:value}]..... which results in the following
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data, which I guess are the []'s inside the object. How can I create the json object in the foreach loop to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. I was echoing $json_array inside the foreach loop.